# Sqoop export to MySQL from HDFS

Tags: mysql, csv, export, sqoop, parquet

I have CSV file in HDFS. The contents are below.

```
1,sam
2,ram
3,Tim,Ny
4,Jim,CA
```

Now I want to export this file into MySQL table.
The MySQL table has following columns `id` `name` `city`

I am getting sqoop export failed error.

This is the sqoop export statement I am using.

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://xxxx/test --username xxxxx --password xxxxx --table test --export-dir /user/xxxxx/testing -m 1 --input-fields-terminated-by ',' --input-null-string '\n' --input-null-non-string '\n'
```

Why I am I getting this error and what is the correct way to get the export done without errors. What if the file is in parquet format.

error code:

`2017-03-20 15:32:37,388 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: 
2017-03-20 15:32:37,388 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: Exception raised during data export
2017-03-20 15:32:37,388 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: 
2017-03-20 15:32:37,388 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: Exception: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: 'sam'
    at test1.__loadFromFields(test1.java:335)
    at test1.parse(test1.java:268)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:89)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:834)
    at test1.__loadFromFields(test1.java:330)`

Comment: Please share error logs. AFAIK you can export parquet data using sqoop.

Comment: @devツ posted error code

Comment: @devツ when I use --input-fields-terminated-by ',' --input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N' --input-lines-terminated-by "\n" records 3 and 4 are exported, but not the 1st and 2nd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused due to the different schema for first two and last two rows.

```
1,sam
2,ram
3,Tim,Ny
4,Jim,CA
```

Sqoop is expecting `,` after `sam` and `ram`. Last column could be empty but `,` should be there.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the last column in your CSV data, so it does not recognize the last column and ends the line with the default properties of mysql and end with error**

**so create csv like**

1,sam,

2,ram,

3,Tim,Ny

4,Jim,CA

**run following sqoop export command**

sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test --username xxxx --password xxxx --table test --export-dir stack/stack.csv -m 1

thanks